How to Fetch User Skills, Education, and Positions from LinkedIn API?
All the supports and forums are saying that to access user profile information, we need the r_fullprofile and r_emailaddress scopes. Unfortunately, these scopes have been deprecated in the new API version, and I'm unable to find a suitable alternative.
I've tried using various endpoints, such as:
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me/skills?projection=(elements*(id,name))
However, I keep receiving the error message: "No virtual resource found."
Here are the steps I've taken so far:
Authenticated the user using OAuth 2.0.
Requested the r_liteprofile and r_emailaddress scopes during authentication.
Attempted to access user skills and other profile information using the new API endpoints.
Is there a way to fetch user skills, education, and positions without the deprecated scopes? If so, could you provide guidance on the correct endpoints and scopes to use? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
